# Create directory at execution time MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am uploading file in database using it's byte[]. To save file in dictionary at executable location, I am using following code. But it is working in MVC 6

```
protected string CreateDirectory()
        {
            try
            {
                string strDirPath = string.Empty;
                #region Create directory at executable location
                string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
                string dir = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
                string dirFolderName = "\\Uploads";
                #endregion
                //Create Directory at executable path
                if (!Directory.Exists(dir + dirFolderName))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + dirFolderName);
                }
                strDirPath = dir + dirFolderName;
                return strDirPath;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
            }

        }
```

This code is giving error like below :

```
CS0117  'Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'GetExecutingAssembly' ProjectName.DNX Core 5.0
```

Please help me for how to create dictionary in MVC 6

Comment: Consider to use `IApplicationEnvironment`, which has `ApplicationBasePath` property. You can use some setting in `appsettings.json` to get the path for saving the files (`UploadsPath` setting). It's very simple and it will gives your application more configuration possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

use

`typeof(SomeClassInTheCurrentlyExecutingAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location`.

Since you are using DNX 5.0, `GetExecutingAssembly()` does not exist.

Comment: Hi Daryal, thanks for reply ASAP. But Instead of 'SomeClassInTheCurrentlyExecutingAssembly', what I have to specify ? Not getting

Comment: It can be any class from your assembly. If you have more than one assemblies, just select a class from the assembly in which CreateDirectory is defined.

Comment: Hi, I have added class but now giving error like :  Error CS1061 'Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'Assembly' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ProjectNAme.DNX Core 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to not target the DNX Core 5.0 framework. If you don't need it at this time you could remove the entry `dnxcore50` from the project.json file in your project.
Change it from

```
"frameworks": {
"dnx451": {
  "dependencies": {
  }
},
"dnxcore50": { }
```

to

```
"frameworks": {
"dnx451": {
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```